# Why is ble beacon shown after disconnecting power by AltBeacon Library?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bluetooth, altbeacon

I use AltBeacon library for simple ble scanning. Scanning for about 7 or 8 seconds then I stop it. tapping button for rescanning. the problem that I have had from the previous version of this library , when I scan then stop it, and disconnect beacon power and I rescan , rangenotifier or observer(another method to watch beacons) could see disconnected beacon! for first time after disconnected it is happened. after that works correctly and if I do the whole process again it is happens.

in the previous library version I had to bind and unbind each time.(not good approach but I had to do) .but in newer version there are no unbind or bind methods. most of methods and functions are deprecated.
I use scanner in fragment. even it is not matter if switch to another fragment. when I come back to scanning fragment again it finds disconnected beacon for fist time after beacon power disconnected. I'm not sure if this library is suitable for a simple bacon scanning. But it is very powerful and simplified some complex thing.

```
    class ScanningFragment() : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment(){

    lateinit var beaconManager:BeaconManager
    lateinit var region:Region

    val rangeNotifier =object:RangeNotifier{
        override fun didRangeBeaconsInRegion(beacons: MutableCollection<Beacon>?, region: Region?) {
            Log.d(TAG,"in didRangeBeacon")
            if (beacons!!.size > 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "didRangeBeaconsInRegion called count:  " + beacons.size + beacons.iterator().next().id1)
                val firstBeacon = beacons.iterator().next()
            }

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        Log.d("lifecycl","it is oncreate ")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        BeaconManager.setDebug(true)

        beaconManager=BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(requireContext()).apply {
            foregroundScanPeriod=7000L
            foregroundBetweenScanPeriod=5000L
            updateScanPeriods()
            beaconParsers.clear()
            beaconParsers.add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-8,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"))
            region = Region("prefixRegion", Identifier.parse("0x0000000000"), null, null)

        }
        setupPermissions()
    }
   
       fun rangingButtonTapped() {
       if (beaconManager.rangedRegions.size == 0) {
                beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(rangeNotifier)
                beaconManager.startRangingBeacons(region)
                binding.insideviewmodel?.isScanning?.value = true
             }
        else {
            beaconManager.stopRangingBeacons(region)
            binding.BTNScan.run {
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({ stopAnimation() }, 1000)
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({ revertAnimation() }, 2000)
            }
        }

      override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           binding.insideviewmodel?.isScanning?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,Observer{
            currentStatusScan->
            if(currentStatusScan)
            {
                object : CountDownTimer(8500, 1000) {
                    override fun onTick(p0: Long) {

                    }

                    override fun onFinish() {
                        beaconManager.stopRangingBeacons(region)
                        beaconManager.removeRangeNotifier(rangeNotifier)
                        binding.insideviewmodel?.isScanning?.value = false
                    }
                }.start()
            }
        })
}

   }
   }
```

it is a debug log for first time scanning.
https://jpst.it/2LVY4

it is a debug log for rescanning after disconnecting beacon power.
https://jpst.it/2LVZs

Profiler:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The second log line "after disconnecting beacon power" shows that the Android OS BLE scanner does indeed deliver an iBeacon detection at 12:53:31:

`2022-02-24 12:53:31.117 23528-23528/ D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop: got record` ... `Processing pdu type FF: 0201041aff4c000215...`.

The library source code shows that this log line is issued immediately upon a callback from the operating system about a BLE advertisement detection.  [See here.](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/service/scanner/CycledLeScannerForLollipop.java#L342)

Clearly it is not possible for a Bluetooth scanner to detect an advertisement from a powered-off BLE device so there must be an alternate explanation.  A few possibilities:

1. The BLE transmitter is not really powered off at (or slightly before) 12:53:31.117
2. The detected advertisement comes from a different transmitter
3. The callback from the Android OS is delayed, perhaps because the main thread on which is delivered was blocked by lots of CPU usage in the app.
4. Some flaw in the bluetooth stack or UI thread handling for the phone in question is delaying delivery of detections.

In order to figure out the cause I would suggest the following:

1. To eliminate a bluetooth stack flaw, test the same code on a different Android phone, preferably by a different manufacturer.
2. To eliminate the possibility of the UI thread being blocked, run this in the Android Studio profiler, or simply cut out as much code as possible that executes before the delay is seen.
3. To verify the transmitter is really off and that there are no other transmitters around, use a second phone with an off the shelf beacon scanner to monitor what devices are actually transmitting.  Only perform your test when you confirm with a second device there are no other visible transmitters.

Comment: thanks David for your concern . at first I'm sure there is no any beacon around me. I even filtered devices to just ibeacon category.  about turning off I'm sure too.
I opened new project and just put a fragment inside activity and test it again. it happens again. I upload Profiler picture to main post.  
I put the simple project on GitHub : https://github.com/NimaaZx/testble . 
I tested on A51 Samsung too and nothing has changed.
please If it is possible see or fork my project. I can open issue to git project page.

Comment: Can you reproduce with the official reference app?  https://github.com/davidgyoung/android-beacon-library-reference-kotlin

Comment: sorry for delay. I used and  edited your kotlin source code a little as I wanted. I removed "BeaconReferenceApplication" object from MainActivity and manifest. because we don't need bg scanning here.

still there is a problem. I connect beacon power, click on Start ranging in app, it shows beacon , then click on stop. I disconnect beacon power and again click on start ranging . I can see disconnected beacon in listview and Toast .
if you want to run it, please pay attention or edit Identifier.parse("0x0000000000") as beacon filter.

Comment: for limitation of comment section character , I was forced to send  git link separately.

I put it here : https://github.com/NimaaZx/BeaconReference-Edited

Comment: I looked at the Git repo in the comment above, but it contains no changes from the standard BeaconReference app.  The last commit I see is by me: `Author: David G. Young <davidgyoung@gmail.com> Date:   Sun Apr 4 20:43:47 2021 -0400 Upgrades and small bug fixes for library release 2.18-beta.  No longer need to include androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0`

Comment: You are right. Sorry David. I'm not familiar well with GitHub right now. I fixed it . you can see it now. as I tell you before ,  if you want to run it, please pay attention or edit Identifier.parse("0x0000000000") as beacon filter . as well the scenario I wrote it to run the app. 1- Click ranging  and waiting for 7 seconds 2-Stop it by button 3-disconnect power beacon 4-Ranging again...
You can see disconnected beacon.

https://github.com/NimaaZx/BeaconReference-Edited

Comment: Hey David. Did you see the link that I sent later ? I did not want to bother you for my project I had to use Android-Scanner-Compat-Library by NordicSemiconductor.  it is similar to native android BLE API and did scanning . btw please look at my project git link for enhancing your good library and fix the bug if it is possible.